# wavesufer update playbackRate without changing sound pitch

Tags: javascript, html, audio, wavesurfer.js

I am using [wavesufer](https://wavesurfer-js.org/) for generating waves for Audio file and other features around that.

Whenever I try to update playbackRate, sound pitch changes weirdly. I have used below few methods.

```
wavesurfer.audioRate = 2
wavesurfer.backend.setPlaybackRate(2)
wavesurfer.backend.params.audioRate.value = 2
```

I have checked on wavesufer site, blog, documentation but still not clear how to change playbackRate without affecting sound pitch.

Comment: Isn't that the nature of playback at  3x? To the human ear,  at that speed, it's expected to sound weird.

Comment: If we do the same with HTML5 Audio, it works better but with wavesurfer its get funny even at 1.5.

Comment: Maybe normalize the audio source first?

Comment: Audio Normalize is more towards peak and loudness normalization, not sure if its for sound pitch as well. Also, there are millions of Audio files so I am looking for compatibility in wavesurfer itself.

Answer (score 1):

The answer for this is here: https://github.com/katspaugh/wavesurfer.js/issues/149

You need to specify this initialization option in the `create()` call:

```
backend: 'MediaElement'
```

This should preserve the original pitch.